# Understanding $m$-th degeneracy locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $g : E \to F$ be a morphism between two vector bundles (of rank $e,f$ respectively) on an irreducible algebraic variety $X$ (over $\mathbb C$). Then for $0 \leq m \leq \{e,f\}$, one defines the $m'th$ degeneracy locus by $D_m(g) :=\{x \in X| \text{rank}(g_x) \leq m\}$, (where I guess $g_x :E_x \to F_x$ is morphism between stalks of $E,F$ at the point $x$, which is therefore $\mathcal O_X,x \cong \mathbb C$ linear map. Please correct me if this notation is wrong)

We can note that, a linear map has rank $\leq m$ iff all $(m+1) \times (m+1)$ minors. vanishes. But how  do we use that to give a closed subscheme structure on $D_m(g)$?

I have come across the following two descriptions : $(1)$ Locally, $g$ can be represented by an $f × e$ matrix with entries in an affine coordinate ring of $X$. One can then consider the ideal generated by the $(m + 1) × (m + 1)$ minor determinants of this local representation. These local ideals patch together to give an ideal sheaf, which gives $D_m(g)$ the structure of a closed subscheme of $X$.

Here why it does not depend on choice of local trivialization and what is precisely meant by " these local ideals patch"?

Can someone demonstrate this argument with a step by step rigorous proof or a concrete example?

$(2)$ How do we see that this is same  as the zero locus of the section $\Lambda^{m+1}g \in H^0(X, (\Lambda^{m+1}E)^* \otimes \Lambda^{m+1}F)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map $ g : E \rightarrow F $ of vector bundles on a variety $ X $ is a global section of the hom sheaf $ \mathcal{Hom} (E,F) = E^* \otimes F $. Hence $ h = \Lambda^{m+1} g \in \Lambda^{m+1} (E^* \otimes F) =  \Lambda^{m+1} E^* \otimes \Lambda^{m+1} F $. Therefore this section determines a map, we call it $ h $ again, $$ h : \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \Lambda^{m+1} E^* \otimes \Lambda^{m+1} F  $$

The $m$-th degeneracy locus $ D_m(g)$ is by definition the closed subscheme which is defined by the quasicoherent sheaf of ideals given by the image of the dualized map $ h^* : ( \Lambda^{m+1} E^* \otimes \Lambda^{m+1} F )^* \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X $.

Your second question is just linear algebra. To say a linear map $ T : V \rightarrow W $ having rank $ \le m $ is precisely to say that $ \Lambda^{m+1} T : \Lambda^{m+1} V \rightarrow \Lambda^{m+1} W $ is the zero map.

Comment: in your first paragraph you have defined $D_m(g)$ as zero locus of the section $\Lambda^{m+1}g \in H^0(X, (\Lambda^{m+1}E)^* \otimes \Lambda^{m+1}F)$. Now if we take a point $x \in X$ which is in this zero locus, then automatically the stalk map $\Lambda^{m+1} g_x : \Lambda^{m+1} E_x \rightarrow \Lambda^{m+1} F_x$ is zero(?) and hence by the linear algebra statement  $g_x :E_x \to F_x$ has rank $\leq m$, is this the content of "m-th degeneracy locus"? (in the description is it the stalk maps?)and what extra do we achieve by the local gluing construction?

Comment: @New yes, that's correct. I gave a direct description of the closed subscheme structure by giving you the ideal sheaf. If you unwrap the definition I gave into a statement about local coordinates, you'll get the patching description. That will be tedious, that's why I prefer this description.

Comment: thanks. That map is map of stalks? (or that of fiber?)

Comment: It is a map of fibers. There are Bertini type results for the expected codimension (e-m)(f-m) of the degeneracy loci, due to Lazarsfeld, you might be interested in those.